# How to insert a fixed property value into every object inside an array without looping?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Is there any way I can insert a fixed value into every object inside an array? I'm able to achieve the final output by looping. Is there any way I can achieve the final output without using a for/while loop?

Programming Language used: **JavaScript**

Example Array:

```
"cars": [
    { "name":"Ford", "models":"Fiesta" },
    { "name":"BMW", "models":"X1" },
    { "name":"Fiat", "models":"Punto" }
]
```

Required Array : Need to add **type:"diesel"** to each object in the array

```
"cars": [
    { type:"diesel", "name":"Ford", "models":"Fiesta"  },
    { type:"diesel", "name":"BMW", "models":"X1" },
    { type:"diesel", "name":"Fiat", "models":"Punto" }
]
```

Comment: @torazaburo I have succeeded by using a loop. I was wondering if there is any other easy way to do the same?

Comment: There's going to be a loop somewhere, either in your code or in a library function that loops because there are no methods that apply something to every item in an array without looping.  So, asking to do it without a loop is frankly a non-starter.  You could ask for the "cleanest" or "simplest" way to do it (and then the question would probably belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition you will have to loop. The only question is whether you write the loop yourself with `for`, or use something like `forEach` which loops for you.

```
cars.forEach(car => car.type = "diesel")
```

Here is a slightly more functional approach:

```
const addType = type => car => car.type = type;

cars.forEach(addType("diesel"))
```

Yes, this is a bit complicated. `addType` creates a function which sets the `type` property of whatever is passed to it to some value. So `addType("diesel")` is a function which adds `type: "diesel"` to its argument.

Or you could just loop:

```
for (car of cars) car.type == "diesel";
```

The above will mutate the original objects. To create an array of new objects with the added property:

```
cars.map(car => ({...car, type: diesel}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `map` to solve your purpose.

```
   cars.map((obj) => {
        obj.Active = 'false';
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: Seems like `forEach` would be more idiomatic here unless you were making a copy of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#map`.

```js
var automobile = {
  "cars": [
    { "name":"Ford", "models":"Fiesta" },
    { "name":"BMW", "models":"X1" },
    { "name":"Fiat", "models":"Punto" }
]
}

var newArr = automobile["cars"].map((car) =>{
  car['type'] = "diesel";
  return car;
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using forEach

```
var vehicle = {
  "cars": [
    { "name":"Ford", "models":"Fiesta" },
    { "name":"BMW", "models":"X1" },
    { "name":"Fiat", "models":"Punto" }
]
}


vehicle.cars.forEach((car) =>{
  car.type = "diesel";
  return car;
});
console.log(vehicle.cars);
```

Comment: There's a loop inside of `.forEach()`.